# "pipenv" fails with AttributeError after upgrading from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, upgrade, pipenv

I recently upgraded my distro version from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 22.04 and now **pipenv** command does not work. Any solutions to fix this?

```
 > pipenv --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 621, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1018, in parse_args
    rest = Command.parse_args(self, ctx, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 875, in parse_args
    parser = self.make_parser(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 821, in make_parser
    for param in self.get_params(ctx):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 774, in get_params
    help_option = self.get_help_option(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 26, in get_help_option
    from .import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+module+collections+has+no+attribute+MutableMapping

Comment: this is a bug in the packaging of `pipenv` for jammy: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipenv/+bug/1970106

Comment: I'd recommend installing a modern version in a virtualenv instead

Comment: Workaround:
` pip install pipenv `

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had installed pipenv from apt package manager which seems to be an old version.

So, remove the pipenv installed via apt

```
> sudo apt remove pipenv
```

And install it using pip to get the latest version

```
> pip install pipenv
```

Comment: Had the same problem after upgrading from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 11 and this solution helped solved the problem.

Comment: Did anybody file an bug report for debian ?

Comment: Its this one : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipenv/+bug/1970106

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the same error by using

```
sudo apt install python3 pipenv
```